# Bind Model property to multiple fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a model string property: SecurityGroupMapping, which I want to be able to set using one of two lists of strings.  The lists are shown based on the selection given in a radio group assigned to a bool.

I've looked at this post: [MVC 3 Bind Model property to 2 fields (e.g. Other Title)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797721/mvc-3-bind-model-property-to-2-fields-e-g-other-title), but I have a slightly different scenario, and was hoping there was an easy way to disable a field if it's not in use...

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Choose how to assign Users to a Security Group")
</div>
<div class="editor-field" style="width: 300px; display: inline;">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup, false) Map Individual Security Group
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup, true) Use Default Security Group
</div>
<br/>
<div id="ShowUserSecurityGroup">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Map the CSV field for User's Security Group")
    </div>
    <div style="width: 300px; display: inline;">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecurityGroupMapping, new SelectList(Model.CsvFields), "Please Select")
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ShowGroupSecurityGroup">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Default Security Group for all Users")
    </div>
    <div style="width: 300px; display: inline;">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecurityGroupMapping, new SelectList(Model.SecurityGroups), "Please Select")
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$("input[name=\"UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup\"]:radio").change(
    function () {
        var selectedValue = $("input:radio[name=UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup]:checked").val();

        if (selectedValue === "True") {
            $("#ShowGroupSecurityGroup").show();
            $("#ShowUserSecurityGroup").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#ShowGroupSecurityGroup").hide();
            $("#ShowUserSecurityGroup").show();
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

Currently, if I select the first radio button, and populate the first field, then this comes through in the Postback correctly.  If I select the second radio button and populate the second field, then the property comes back as NULL. Is it possible to simply disable a field within a hidden div?

EDIT: The suggestion to disable the element worked with the show hide in the end - I didn't think it would be as simple as just assigning each drop down a different ID, and then disabling it in the JQuery.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecurityGroupMapping, new SelectList(Model.SecurityGroups), "Please Select", new { id = "GroupSecurityGroup" })

$("input[name=\"UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup\"]:radio").change(
    function () {
        var selectedValue = $("input:radio[name=UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup]:checked").val();

        if (selectedValue === "True") {
            $("#UserSecurityGroup").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#GroupSecurityGroup").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#ShowGroupSecurityGroup").show();
            $("#ShowUserSecurityGroup").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#UserSecurityGroup").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#GroupSecurityGroup").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#ShowGroupSecurityGroup").hide();
            $("#ShowUserSecurityGroup").show();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: The problem lies with duplicate ID's being generated for the two dropdown lists. Only the first one is used when the form submits. If you have a fixed number of options, I would just create two separate fields or use a list.

Comment: @EvanMulawski, Duplicate `id` attributes have nothing to do with what's posted (although its invalid html). Its a controls `name` and `value` attributes which are posted in the form data. Because two key/value pairs with the name `SecurityGroupMapping` are posted, the `DefaultModelBinder` binds the first one and ignores the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Based on your radio button selection you should just load the dropdown with different SelectList, instead of hiding/showing.

**Option 2**
Like @Evan Mulawski suggested you can use two separate fields on view and ViewModel. This might be the easiest and simple to do it.

**Option 3**

Instead of hiding/showing dropdowns you can just move them outside/inside of form tag.

```
    $("input[name=\"UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup\"]:radio").change(
           function () 
           {
               var selectedValue = $("input:radio[name=UseDefaultGroupSecurityGroup]:checked").val();
                
               if (selectedValue === "True") {
                  $("#ShowUserSecurityGroup").detach().insertAfter($(this).closest("form"))
                  $("#ShowGroupSecurityGroup").detach().appendTo($(this).closest("form"))                            
               }
               else 
               {
                  $("#ShowUserSecurityGroup").detach().appendTo($(this).closest("form"))
                  $("#ShowGroupSecurityGroup").detach().insertAfter($(this).closest("form"))                                         
               }
           });
```

**Option 4** - The easiest of all

As @Stephen Muecke suggested , disabling/enabling the elements instead of hide/show.

Comment: Another option would be to enable/disable the selects in addition to show/hide - disabled controls do not post back.

Comment: Yes I agree, I forgot about that.

Comment: Thanks guys, I went with Option 4, because I had 3 groups of fields, each with 2 options... so in addition to Security Groups, I was setting Password and Username in the same way, and the appendTo was causing the fields to be moved to the bottom of the form.